# Changing data returned from service changes data in service too

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

When I store data returned from a service in my controller and then edit it, it also changes the data in the service.

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gchameleon/aybLwa2L/1)

```
 /* The backend connection part and the actual markdown editor JS have been removed because it would just make the code huge and is irrelevant to the problem */    

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

// In my app, this service caches blog post data from my server on the client side and returns single posts from it
myApp.factory('PostService', function ($log, $filter, $http) {
    var data;

    // Just an example for data pulled from server
    data = [{
        id: 99999,
        text: "Hello"
    }];

    // Function for returning a post out of the data array loaded from the server
    var getData = function (id) {
        if (id !== undefined) {
            var arr = $filter('filter')(data, {
                id: id
            });
            if (arr.length === 0) {
                $log.error('PostService:: getData(' + id + '):: Post Not Found');
                return 'not_found';
            } else {
                $log.debug('PostService:: getData(' + id + '):: Post returned');
                return arr[0];
            }
        } else {
            return data;
        }
    };
    return {
        getData: getData            
    };
});

function ctrl($log, $scope, PostService) {
    var edit = this;

    // Sample post id
    edit.editingId = 99999;

    // "Copy" (apparrently more "bind") the blog post data to edit.data
    edit.data = PostService.getData(edit.editingId);

}
```

This is used for a markdown editor. I wanted to load the data from the service into the controller, then edit it, and give the service the new version on pressing a "Save" button.
If the aforementioned behaviour is correct in the sense of Angular's databinding, what is a better solution to achieve what I want?

**Update**

Based on [PSL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1009603/psl)'s comment and [Thibaud Sowa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33424724/5504906) I changed the `getData()` function to return a copy using `angular.copy()`. However, it seems not to be possible to copy one object out of an array (like `angular.copy(arr[0])`), as it will still return the whole array. See the [updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gchameleon/aybLwa2L/2/).

**Update 2**

Well, I was dumb. I corrected it [in the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gchameleon/aybLwa2L/4/). Thank you for your answers.

Comment: this is how services are designed to work in angular.  Why would you *not* want to change the data all the way back up to it's root in the app?

Comment: because you are carrying object reference of service object to controller..and update in that object will update the data in service..

Comment: objects are mutable, that is why an edit in your controller is reflected in your service, which is not necessarily good in terms of maintaining proper state of your app. While returning the data from the service clone  it using `angular.copy`. I would not necessarily agree to the comment `this is how services are designed to work in angular`. Because that is a bad thing unless you are writing some small test app or a POC. You should avoid mutating the state of the your application in a non-explicit way, most design patterns follow that including FLUX and immutable data stores.

Comment: also, you didn't save your fiddle link; what is posted is a generic app using angular 1.0.1 (probably not what you want).

Comment: @Claies I use the service to store the blog posts across multiple ui-router states. The one I mention here is the editor. The service also supplies the posts to for example the home page. I wouldn't want to update it because it changes the post until I reload the page, and I want it only to do that when I press the save button. That's why I asked for a better solution. Should I use a second data set in the service for editing? Good to know anyway, that wasn't exactly clear to me.

Comment: @PSL That is why I thought, it somehow didn't seem right. As explained in my last comment, the service is used across multiple states.

Comment: @Claies I updated the fiddle link.

Comment: @BendeLaporte you should perhaps return a _copy_ of the data from the service and for save accept the data to be saved in your service via an explicit save method, make server call to update and update the local collection in your store. If you want to notify about a change then notify from the initiating component once save is successful so that other component depending upon the same state can refresh itself. You might want to take a look at _flux_ or even _RXObservables_ especially to achieve a better design especially if you have a fairly larger app.

Comment: @PSL I have those methods (putData) and also a notifier structure, because I did not understand how services are _supposed_ to work. See my updated question. Thanks for pointing me to the flux architecture thing, sounds quite interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are returning an object. In javascript when you do that it's like if you are passing a pointer.

You should use angular.copy to copy the object field by field, like this:

```
        return angular.copy(data);
```

See the doc here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy

**Response to your update**

Well, I edited your fiddle, to show you that you can copy an item of an array. Actually it's seems that every thing works like you want... (Or I didn't understand your need!)

The updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/thibaudsowa/aybLwa2L/3/

Comment: The problem here is that it does not seem possible to deep copy an object out of an array as explained in my updated question.

Comment: I just forgot to include the ID in the function call in the controller, which of course returns the whole array. I feel so stupid^^

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple solution to your problem:

If you dont want to change the data you get from the service make a copy

There are plenty of threads on SO discussing the fastes or most elegant way to deep copy a Javascript object. A simple and rather fast solution is using json parse and stringify like this:

```
var copyOfA = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a));
```

Apply this to the data you get from your service and you are good to go :)